# Can we split a splittable link by applying Reidemeister moves to non-self crossings only

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

Suppose $L=K_1 \cup K_2$ is a link consisting of two components $K _1$ and $K_2$ With some non-self crossings between  $K _1$ and $K_2$ . Suppose $L$ is isotopic to the unlink, then can we split the two components by just applying Reidemeister moves to the crossings between $K _1$ and $K_2$ and keep the self crossings unchanged ?

Comment: Can you clarify what moves are allowed?  For instance, is a strand of $K_1$ allowed to pass through a self-crossing of $K_2$ via a Reidemeister 3 move?  If so, then the question is whether the unlink can be split where after every step, the knot diagrams we get by removing $K_1$ or $K_2$ never changes.  If not, then the question is whether the knotted graph obtained by fusing self-crossings to become degree-4 vertices can be split.